# Implicit & Explicit QR algorithms & non-convergence

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been working with the matrix below:-

\begin{pmatrix}
8 & -2 & 1 & -1 \\
23 & -6 & 3 & -3 \\
-4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
-4 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}

It's eigenvalues are {1,1,1,1}. I have my own program that implements the implicit version of the QR algorithm, and also another than implements the explicit version of it.

I have tested this matrix on some online eigenvalue finders, and most of them return the correct answer of {1,1,1,1}, however the version of Mathcad that I own returns values that are close to, but not exactly equal to one. In fact, they even have small imaginary components.

My own implicit QR returns similar values, and I cannot seem to encourage it to hone in on precisely '1'. However, my explicit version produces the correct values.

Any idea what is going on here? Is it that the explicit version, although slower, is more 'numerically robust' than the implicit?

Regards
Jeremy Watts

Answer (score 1):

Matrix

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
8 & -2 & 1 & -1 \\
23 & -6 & 3 & -3 \\
-4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
-4 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Some important facts:

1) The Jordan form of matrix $M$ is $M=PJP^{-1}$ with

$$J=\begin{pmatrix}
     1  &   1  &   0   &  0\\
     0  &   1  &   1 &    0\\
     0   &  0  &   1  &   1\\
     0  &   0  &   0  &   1
\end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{and} \ \ P=\begin{pmatrix}
    -6   &  3  &   7  &   1\\
   -12   &  0  &  23  &   0\\
     6  &  -9  &  -4  &   0\\
   -12  &  18  &  -4  &   0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

2) This Jordan form means that $1$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity 4, but with a dimension 1 associated eigenspace (directed by $(1,2,-1,2)^T$). We are far from the diagonalizable case.

3) Matlab, known for its accuracy in all its basic algorithms, gives (as you have had) eigenvalues that are not equal to 1:

$$0.9998 \pm 0.0002i, \ \ \  \ 1.0002 \pm 0.0002i$$

4) The condition number of $M$ is rather high : around $10^3.$

(I assume that Matlab uses a variant of QR algorithm for computing eigenvalues)

Besides these observations, I have no simple explanation.

Remark:

I have been able to reconstruct a similar example by defining

$M_1:=P_1JP_1^{-1} \ \ \text{with}$

$$ M_1:=\begin{pmatrix}
   -2  &  6 &  -4 &  1\\
   -1  &  2 &   0  & 0\\
    0  & -1  &  2 &  0 \\
    0  &  0  & -1  & 2
\end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ and \ \ \ \ P_1:=\begin{pmatrix}
     1  &   1   &  1  &   1\\
     1  &   2  &   3   &  4\\
     1  &   3  &   6  &  10\\
     1  &   4  &  10  &  20
\end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{known as Pascal's matrix}$$

with eigenvalues that should be $1$ but that are found, by Matlab, to be:

$$\{0.9997 + 0.0000i, \ 1.0000 + 0.0003i, \ 1.0000 - 0.0003i, \ 1.0003 + 0.0000i\}$$

May I ask you to test $M_1$ with your code and say if the same phenomena occur ?

(this time, $\det(P_1)=1$ whereas, in the case of the problem, $\det(P)=1296.$)

---

Edit: I have defined the same matrices as just above, by $8 \times 8$ instead of $4 \times 4$ ; the phenomenon takes a much larger amplitude (incertitude multiplied by $\approx 10^2$ !):

$$\{0.9336, \ \ \ 0.9542 \pm 0.0473i, \ \ \ 1.0012 \pm 0.0648i, \ \ \ 1.0458 \pm 0.0449i, \ \ \ 1.0641 \}.$$

Comment: Many thanks for your time & effort. It is somewhat heartening to see that even Matlab doesn't get the perfect answer.

Comment: Yes. I have just a little reshaped my redaction in order to place Jordan reduced form in the forefront. I think this is a key to the explanation. Surely the phenomenon is amplified if the dimensions of matrices is increased. I have to check it...

Comment: I checked your M1 matrix using my code, and the implicit version gave results similar to your Matlab's. They were:-

0.99975
1.00002 + 2.33321E-4i
1.00002 - 2.3332093E-4i
1.0002

Comment: On my side, as I have said upwards, I have increased the size of the matrices: the results are striking; see the Edit I have added to my answer.